# Algebra dense in the uniform topology on continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that the algebra generated by $x^{2014n+718}$ $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$ is dense in the uniform topology on $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Since the function $x^{718}$ separates points in the interval $[0,1]$ the Stone Weierstrass theorem says that the algebra is dense in the topology.

In my class's definition of algebra we assume that all constants are in the algebra so $1$ is in the algebra.

Does this approach seem correct?